# What do you call a single "shot" or "explosion" in a firework?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am organizing a support event for a firework display.

If someone buys a 2000円 ticket, it will pay for another "firework unit" being launched in the sky.

In Japanese we say "一発", but is there an equivalent word in English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most natural thing to say is simply *firework*:

> Every time someone buys a ticket, it will fund one more firework.

Answer (score 4):

The fireworks industry specific word is *shell*. As in *artillery shell*.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> Fireworks device/A stick of fireworks/A pyrotechnic composition/A  burst of fireworks?

As in, everytime somebody buys a ticket, it funds one more fireworks device